# Why config file is not made in Activiti projects?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, activiti

I am a beginner of Apache Activiti API. After installing Activiti and its Eclipse Plugin according to the [Activiti's tutorial](https://www.activiti.org/userguide/), I make an activiti project and included Activiti's jar files in the project but no config file(such as activiti.cfg.xml) is made. Please guide me how to create an Activiti project which can communicate with Activiti API.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own `activiti.cfg.xml` file in your **project classpath**. follow [*Activiti Doc on Configuration*](https://www.activiti.org/userguide/#_configuration) for example.